# angular testing dynamic tabs component

Tags: angular

I have a `TabsComponent`, that accepts `TabComponent`s as content children. My goal is to test `TabsComponent`, so for that purpose I have created a wrapper component:

```
const tabs = [
  { id: '1', title: 'title1', content: 'content1' },
  { id: '2', title: 'title2', content: 'content2' }
]

@Component({
  selector: 'my-tabs-test-wrapper',
  template: `
       <my-tabs>
         <my-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [tabId]="tab.id" [tabTitle]="tab.title">
            {{ tab.content }}
         </my-tab>
       </my-tabs>
`})
class TabsTestWrapper {}
```

One of my tests is to check that two components of type `TabComponent` are rendered, but my test fails - I get zero items instead of two. However, when I replace the ngFor loop with two hard coded `my-tab` items, two items are counted and the test passes. How can I make it work with a dynamic list?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you are creating one component, just to test another. Either way though, your class as shown above isn't being given any tabs, which is why it isn't rendering any. You probably want `class TabsTestWrapper {tabs = [{ id: '1' ...}];}`

Comment: @peinearydevelopment but there is a tab const defined above the component

Comment: exactly my point, that isn't a property of the component, but a variable outside of the component, therefore, angular won't use it for its binding/rendering.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this isn't the way you would test your components. You shouldn't have to create one component to test another.

For your specific question though, update your code to include your tabs as a property on your component and not a const outside of your component. Angular only uses properties on your component for its data binding. Your `const` value is outside of that component and therefor won't be used in the component's rendering process.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-tabs-test-wrapper',
  template: `
       <my-tabs>
         <my-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [tabId]="tab.id" [tabTitle]="tab.title">
            {{ tab.content }}
         </my-tab>
       </my-tabs>
`})
class TabsTestWrapper {
tabs = [
  { id: '1', title: 'title1', content: 'content1' },
  { id: '2', title: 'title2', content: 'content2' }
]}
```